# what should write in parameter of wp_get_attachment_image_src() in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i m using wp_get_attachment_image_src()in my template file of wordpress. and i want image from this url.

```
http://localhost/....../wp-content/uploads/2014/02/AceBailBondsKS.png
```

then what to write in parameter of this function i have used following.:-
syntax:- `<?php wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size, $icon ); ?>` 
then in place of $attachment_id what id should i pass 2014 or 2?
i have used like this

```
 wp_get_attachment_image_src(2014)
```

Thanks very much for any help anyone can give.

Comment: none...

You need to write `attachment_id` from `wp-admin ->> media ->> your file`

Comment: hello @akshay 2014 or 02?

Comment: If you know full url of your file that direct insert it like this:--

`$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$file_url = $upload_dir['baseurl']."/2014/02/AceBailBondsKS.png";`

Comment: None of from `2014, 02`

Comment: See this will help you -- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir

Comment: Please don't use the method shown above. It's a bad practise. You're original idea of using the wp_get_attachment_image_src is the correct way of getting the image url.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your WordPress admin media library and locate the image file. Take note of the Media ID.

When you click on the image in the media library look at the URL. It should say &post=123 - The value here (123) is the media ID.

This is the ID you enter.

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src( 123 );
```